# Stylus css prepending 'ks-' to css rem unit. Why?

Tags: stylus, stylus-loader

I'm trying to write a simple function to generate utility classes with Stylus:

```
spacer-maker($class, $property, $steps = 12)

  for $i in 1..$steps

    if $i < 5
      $step = .25
      $multiplier = $i
    else
      $step = 1
      $multiplier = $i - 3

    $value = $multiplier * $step

    .{$class}-{$i}
      {$property}: $value rem

spacer-maker('mt', 'margin-top')
```

This is working as expected EXCEPT the unit value rendered is `ks-rem` not `rem`:

```
.mt-1 {
  margin-top: 0.25 ks-rem;
}
```

I can't see any reason for this to happen, and have been trying all matter of workarounds to just output `rem` correctly but cannot find a working solution.

I'm using webpack driven compilation but have not had any other Stylus compilation issue to date.

Comment: Running this exact code thru the pure stylus compiler seems fine. So the issue must be with the compilation process via webpack

Comment: I found a fix for this that is mostly a workaround. My multiplying the $value property by '1rem' rather than just trying to render 'rem' on the end everything works as expected